# D3 path animation- can't read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm getting the aforementioned error and can't figure out why.

I think it's some arcane issue with how d3 is handling the JSON data.  The error throws when I try   I have verified in the console that everything seems to be behaving as it should, including getting the NestedDataX, Y, and the newData.  It must not be liking how I'm feeding data in, but actual documentation on how the .data()

The idea is that in my code I need to convert the GeoJSON to a readable format by storing the X coordinates (which are several layers deep) and the Y coordinates (which also are) and load them into a new array which will make it easier to work with.  I had tried using .nest() but I couldn't get it to give me the data I wanted.

```
//Script will be included with an enqueue hook elswhere
//Google API will be included with an enqueue hook elsewhere 

$(document).ready(function() {
  d3.json("http://localhost/trip_animate/tripData.geojson")
    .then(function(data) {

      console.log("It just works");
      /*********
      Container
      *********/
      var svgContainer = d3.select("#svg2").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 1000)
        .attr("height", 1000);

      /************
      Scales
      ************/
      var width = 1000;
      var height = 1000;

      //TODO

      var x = d3.scaleTime()
        .range([0, width]);
      var y = d3.scaleTime()
        .range([height, 0]);


      var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
        .scale(x);

      var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
        .scale(y);
      //CREATE, THEN MODIFY
      /**********
          Format data for usage with our animation
          ***********/

      var i;
      var j;

      var arrLength = data.features[0]["geometry"]["coordinates"].length;

      /***********
          Create variable to bind x data to
          ***********/
      var nestedDataX = [];
      for (i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
        nestedDataX[i] = data.features[0]["geometry"]["coordinates"][i][0];
      }

      var nestedDataY = [];
      for (i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
        nestedDataY[i] = data.features[0]["geometry"]["coordinates"][i][1];
      }

      var newData = {
        "x": nestedDataX,
        "y": nestedDataY
      }

      /**********
          Accessor 
          **********/
      var lineFunction2 = d3.line(newData)
        .x(function(d) {
          return x(d.x);
        })
        .y(function(d) {
          return y(d.y);
        })
        .curve(d3.curveBasis);
      /********
          Drawer - Not sure about this one
          ********/
      var tripLine = svgContainer.append("path")
        .data(newData)
        .style("stroke-dasharray", "4,4")
        .attr("d", lineFunction2()) //ERROR THROWS HERE!!!
        .transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .style("stroke", "#ddd")
        .attr("stroke", "red")
        .attr("stroke-width", 4)
        .attr("fill", "none");

    });
});
```

The JSON is of the format GEOJSON, which is in the format:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "name": "Test Drive for data ",
                "time": "2018-04-03T01:48:51Z",
                "coordTimes": [//ARRAY OF DATETIMES] },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [ //ARRAY OF X, Y, and ELEVATION COORDINATES]    
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues in your code.

The main issue is this: in D3, the `data` method accept three things:

1. An array;
2. A function;
3. Nothing.

Right now, your `newData` is an object, so nothing will show up (unless you change the method to `datum`, which we will do, but for another reason, see below).

A possible solution is passing the array directly:

```
var tripLine = svg.append("path")
    .datum(data.features[0].geometry.coordinates)
```

And changing the line generator:

```
var lineFunction = d3.line()
    .x(function(d){return d[0]})
    .y(function(d){return d[1]})
    .curve(d3.curveBasis);
```

Minor issues:

1. You can't pass data to `d3.line` like this: `d3.line(data)`;
2. Use `datum`, not `data`: you have a single path here, and no enter selection;
3. Don't call the `lineFunction2`, remove the parentheses: `.attr("d", lineFunction)`;
4. You're using `attr` and `style` to change the fill of the path *after* the transition. Whatever is the purpose of this, it won't work.

Here is a simplified version of the code with those changes, and fake data:

```js
var data = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "name": "Test Drive for data ",
      "time": "2018-04-03T01:48:51Z",
      "coordTimes": []
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "LineString",
      "coordinates": [
        [10, 10, 10],
        [30, 40, 10],
        [50, 20, 10],
        [70, 100, 10],
        [90, 20, 10],
        [110, 120, 10],
        [130, 100, 10],
        [150, 80, 10]
      ]
    }
  }]
}

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var lineFunction = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return d[0]
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return d[1]
  })
  .curve(d3.curveBasis);

var tripLine = svg.append("path")
  .datum(data.features[0].geometry.coordinates)
  .style("stroke-dasharray", "4,4")
  .attr("d", lineFunction)
  .style("stroke", "#ddd")
  .transition()
  .duration(2000)
  .style("stroke", "red")
  .attr("stroke-width", 4)
  .attr("fill", "none");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```